# Is there a way to get dialpad input through dialogflow telephony

Tags: node.js, dialogflow-es

I had written a node js server code so that dialog-flow can connect to my server through web-hook and integrated dialog-flow phone gateway. I am able to get the voice transcript text when made call to that number. But if i type any number on dial-pad i am not getting it. Is there any thing i should do to get the number input from dial-pad on call.

The response is something like this if i say 'hello' on call.

```
{
  "responseId":"b5644842-75bf-41f3-bf84-cf7b4f02c71f",
  "queryResult": :{
      "queryText":"Hello.","action":
      "input.welcome",
      "parameters":{},
      "allRequiredParamsPresent":true,
      "intent":{
          "name":"projects/maps-ec9e1/agent/intents/54f5f623-2011-4d95-92a7-b8e873cd55a7",
         "displayName":"Default Welcome Intent"
       },
      "intentDetectionConfidence":1,
      "languageCode":"en-us"
   },
   "originalDetectIntentRequest":{
      "source":"GOOGLE_TELEPHONY",
      "payload":{
        "telephony":{     
          "caller_id":"REDACTED_IN_STANDARD_TIER_AGENT"
         }
      }
    },
   "session":"projects/maps-ec9e1/agent/sessions/l0vQqOpaSsq9rvJc0sMMYA"
   } 
}
```

Comment: I too wold like to know if this is possible.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for DTMF detection. Google's Dialogflow Phone Gateway does not support this, but you can get this capability from some third party Dialogflow Gateway products like Voximplant, Audiocodes' VoiceAI Gateway, and [drachtio.org](https://github.com/davehorton/drachtio-dialogflow-phone-gateway).

There is no standard method for how to do this, but generally the telephony gateway needs to detect a digit and then sends a text query or event to Dialogflow where your bot can handle it.

I wrote reviews at cogint.ai with details on how to do this for [Voximplant](https://cogint.ai/voximplant-dialogflow-connector-2019/#dtmfdetection) and [Audiocodes](https://cogint.ai/audiocodes-voice-ai-gateway-review/#dtmfdetection).